# Books or other resources for Java to Cocoa transition

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've learned Java (including Android) and am looking to make the transition to programming in Objective-C / Cocoa for Mac OS X, trying to figure out what books or other resources to use. I would like to jump into it as quickly as possible; I'm fine not learning aspects of C that aren't in Objective-C (subjective C??). I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135112/java-developer-meets-objective-c-on-mac-os) but the OP there already knows C; [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322513/learning-objective-c-with-a-java-background) is helpful but a bit more general than what I'm looking for (I already know that I'd like to jump straight into Objective-C if possible).

Many, many people ([here, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945600/book-recomendations-for-learning-cocoa-programming)) recommend Aaron Hillegass's *Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X* as the Cocoa textbook. I intend to use it. But will it be understandable to me if I only know Java but not Objective-C already? I had thought about first using Stephen Kochan's *Programming in Objective-C* (also highly recommended) to learn the Objective-C basics, but that book looks like a general intro to programming, where I'd need to sit through a bunch of stuff I already know. Should I try a Java-developer-specific book like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223693)? If so, will I still need Hillegass in addition, or will it be enough? Alternately, can I just read a few quick online docs that will guide me through the Java / OC differences, and then go straight to Hillegass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, *Learn Objective-C for Java Developers* not only covers the differences between the languages (mostly minor), but it has good insights into the implications of those differences.  But yes, that would not cover Cocoa.  After brushing up on Objective C, Hillegass's book is really great for Cocoa in relation to the X-Code and Interface Builder tools.  I'm not sure of good 'tuts' online, but obviously sites like SO are best for specific questions you may have down the road.
 Hillegass's book however, as per its title, emphasizes Cocoa and MAC OS, not Cocoa Touch and iOS.